# unix DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD (var) var prototype?

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel

i want to work with 2 queue in the module where i change my pointer to them 
therefore i need to use :

```
//declartion
wait_queue_head_t **currentQ;
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD (readWaitQ1);
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD (readWaitQ2);

if(condition){
    currentQ = &readWaitQ1;
}else{
    currentQ = &readWaitQ2;
}
```

but i get incorrect type for wake_up an other stuff using the queue.
even thought i google it i couldnt find an answer can someone just give me the prototype needed?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the macro is (see [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/wait.h#L74)):

```
#define DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(name) \
    wait_queue_head_t name = __WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD_INITIALIZER(name)
```

that means that:

```
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD (readWaitQ1);
```

translates to:

```
wait_queue_head_t readWaitQ1 = ...;
```

Now with your current code:

```
wait_queue_head_t **currentQ;
currentQ = &readWaitQ1;
```

you have one too many indirections on `currentQ`. You should try:

```
wait_queue_head_t *currentQ;
```

instead.

Comment: thanks , i used other functiones where the compiler didnt yelled at me and that got me confused